# VHDL: Booth's multiplication algorithm process block not working as intended?

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, multiplier, algorithm

I am trying to implement Booth's multiplication algorithm using [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcnx.org%2Fcontents%2FZxCI0OEL%401%2FBooth-s-Algorithm&psig=AOvVaw2tQEYYvLF5KAVDP4rn2a2Q&ust=1667807360402000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjRxqFwoTCNi_mdyImfsCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE) flowchart in VHDL. So far, I have written the code below:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity mult is
    generic(N : integer);                           -- no of bits
    port(clock        : in  std_logic;
         reset        : in  std_logic;
         multiplicand : in  signed(N downto 1);     -- multiplicand
         multiplier   : in  signed(N downto 1);     -- mulitplier
         product      : out signed(2*N downto 1);   -- product
         valid        : out std_logic);             -- product-valid bit
end mult;

architecture booth of mult is
    signal M    : signed(N downto 1);
    signal Q    : signed(N downto 1);
    signal A    : signed(N downto 1);               -- accumulator
    signal q0   : std_logic;                        -- control signal
    signal cnt  : integer range N downto 0;         -- counter
begin

    process(clock, reset) is
    begin

        -- initialize registers
        if reset = '1' then
            M   <= multiplicand;
            Q   <= multiplier;
            q0  <= '0';
            A   <= (others => '0');
            cnt <= N;

        elsif rising_edge(clock) and (cnt > 0) then

            ------------------------------BLOCK 1 (ADD/SUB)------------------------------
            if Q(1) = '0' and q0 = '1' then
                report "adding";
                A <= A + M;
            elsif Q(1) = '1' and q0 = '0' then
                report "subtracting";
                A <= A - M;
            end if;
            -----------------------------BLOCK 1 (ADD/SUB)----------------------------

            ----------------------------BLOCK 2 (SHIFT)------------------------------
            q0 <= Q(1);
            
            for i in 1 to N loop
                if i = N then
                    Q(i) <= A(1);
                else
                    Q(i) <= Q(i + 1);
                end if;
            end loop;

            for i in 1 to N loop
                if i = N then
                    A(i) <= A(N);
                else
                    A(i) <= A(i + 1);
                end if;
            end loop;
            -----------------------------BLOCK 2 (SHIFT)------------------------------

            -- decrement counter
            cnt <= cnt - 1;

        end if;
    end process;

    -- product consists of the two registers A and Q as higher and lower words
    product <= A & Q;

    -- set valid bit indicating if product has been fully computed (after N clock cycles)
    valid <= '1' when cnt = 0 else
             '0';

end booth;
```

The issue that I ran into (after trying to debug for quite some time) is that the blocks 1 and 2, labelled "ADD/SUB" and "SHIFT" for some reason are not producing the desired results when kept in the code together. I have tried commenting out one block and letting the other remain and they seem to work just fine on their own. However when executed together they produce results I cannot explain. In a process block, code is supposed to be executed sequentially right ?

The numbers that I have tried in the testbench are: "-7" and "3". Here is the code for the testbench:

````vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity mult_tb is
end mult_tb;

architecture sim of mult_tb is
    constant N            : integer                := 4;
    constant cycle        : time                   := 10 ns;
    signal   clock        : std_logic              := '1';
    signal   reset        : std_logic              := '1';
    signal   multiplicand : signed(N downto 1)     := "1001"; -- signed -7 (2's complmnt)
    signal   multiplier   : signed(N downto 1)     := "0011"; -- signed 3
    signal   product      : signed(2*N downto 1);
    signal   valid        : std_logic;
begin
    clock <= not clock after cycle/2;
    uut : entity work.mult(booth)
          generic map(N => N)
          port map(multiplicand => multiplicand,
                   multiplier   => multiplier,
                   clock        => clock,
                   reset        => reset,
                   product      => product,
                   valid        => valid);
    process begin
        wait for 0.3*cycle;                 -- reset for less than a cycle
        reset <= '0'; wait for 8*cycle;     -- then bring dut out of reset
        wait;
    end process;
end sim;
```
````

Comment: I enjoyed learning about Booth's many decades ago. Didn't implement it at the time in VHDL or Verilog as VHDL was at the time more about documentation and Verilog was still inaccessible to me and not really ready for prime time, anyway. If and when I get a moment (may be a few days) I'll see if I can  help. Hopefully, though, someone else will enter in earlier. This is a very common block and well-documented today. Meanwhile, +1 and best wishes.

Comment: Have you allowed for the semantics of signal assignments in a process? If you're not sure, you may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532

Comment: To be honest, this reads like a computer program rather than a digital logic circuit design, with the use of signals rather than some variables and the clock gating. What's your background and also how much experience with VHDL do you have?

Comment: "In a process block, code is supposed to be executed sequentially right?" -> No, not quite. Logic is processed sequentially, but for *signals* updates essentially only occur at the end of the process. So when you set "A" in Block 1, the new value isn't seen by Block 2 until the following clock cycle. You could switch to *variables* instead of *signals*, but that isn't really best practices unless it's counters, flags, etc.

Comment: @ks0ze, I think you know but not describing it properly. OP is correct: a process is carried out sequentially. A separate thing is that signal updates are scheduled to occur at the process end. It's only a confusion if you're comparing VHDL to a programming language, which are entirely different to HDLs as they run instructions on CPUs. Where you're confused is variables vs signals, the choice of which is nothing to do with best practice. In a process, variables describe wiring or nodes in combinatorial logic. Signals are for connections to outside; in a clocked process, they make registers.

Comment: @TonyM, I definitely could have been clearer w/ my comment. I was trying to make the point that only A(0) updates with "A+/-M" results because the reset of the bits A(N downto 1) are updated in the "for" loop using the old values of "A". Best practices may not have been the best phrase, but it's very easy to create incredibly deep logic paths with variables without realizing it if you're coming from a software background as I'm assuming the OP is. Didn't originally see A was being used outside the process too, so it has to be a signal.

Answer (score -1):

The code below has some issues even though it works in a basic simulation.

**ORIGINAL**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity mult is
    generic(N : integer);                           -- no of bits
    port(clock        : in  std_logic;
         reset        : in  std_logic;
         multiplicand : in  unsigned(N downto 1);   -- multiplicand
         multiplier   : in  unsigned(N downto 1);   -- mulitplier
         product      : out unsigned(2*N downto 1); -- product
         valid        : out std_logic);             -- product-valid bit
end mult;

architecture booth of mult is

    -- declare abstract states
    type abstract_state is (addsub, shift);
    signal state : abstract_state;

    -- declare internal registers
    signal M     : unsigned(N downto 1);
    signal Q     : unsigned(N downto 1);
    signal A     : unsigned(N downto 1);                -- accumulator
    signal q0    : std_logic;                           -- control signal
    signal cnt   : integer range N downto 0;            -- counter

begin

    process(clock, reset) is
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            -- initialize registers
            M     <= multiplicand;
            Q     <= multiplier;
            A     <= (others => '0');
            q0    <= '0';
            cnt   <= N;

        elsif rising_edge(clock) and (cnt > 0) then

            case state is
                when addsub =>
                    state <= shift;
                    if Q(1) = '0' and q0 = '1' then
                        A <= A + M;             -- addition
                    elsif Q(1) = '1' and q0 = '0' then
                        A <= A + (not M) + 1;   -- subtraction (2's complement addition)
                    end if;

                when shift =>
                    state <= addsub;
                    -- arithmetic shift right: A -> Q -> q0 (1 bit)
                    q0 <= Q(1);
                    for i in 1 to N loop
                        if i = N then
                            Q(i) <= A(1);
                        else
                            Q(i) <= Q(i + 1);
                        end if;
                    end loop;
                    for i in 1 to N loop
                        if i = N then
                            A(i) <= A(N);
                        else
                            A(i) <= A(i + 1);
                        end if;
                    end loop;
                    -- decrement counter
                    cnt <= cnt - 1;

            end case;

        end if;
    end process;

    -- product consists of the two registers A and Q as higher and lower words
    product <= (A & Q);
    -- set valid bit indicating if product has been fully computed
    valid <= '1' when cnt = 0 else '0';
end booth;
```

**EDIT**
Here is an updated version of the design which implements the multiplier as an FSM. As pointed out in the comments, the AND gating on the clock edge has been removed.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity mult is
    generic(N : integer);                           -- no of bits
    port(clock        : in  std_logic;
         reset        : in  std_logic;
         multiplicand : in  signed(N downto 1);     -- multiplicand
         multiplier   : in  signed(N downto 1);     -- mulitplier
         product      : out signed(2*N downto 1);   -- product
         valid        : out std_logic;              -- product-valid bit
         state_out    : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0));
end mult;

architecture booth of mult is
    -- declare abstract states and state variable
    type abstract_state is (idle, addsub, shift, done);
    signal state : abstract_state;
    -- declare internal registers
    signal M     : signed(N downto 1);
    signal Q     : signed(N downto 1);
    signal A     : signed(N downto 1);                  -- accumulator
    signal q0    : std_logic;                           -- control signal
    signal count : integer range N downto 0;            -- counter
begin
    process(clock, reset) is
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            state <= idle;
        elsif rising_edge(clock) then
            case state is
                when idle =>
                    state <= addsub;
                when addsub =>
                    state <= shift;
                when shift =>
                    if count = 0 then
                        state <= done;
                    elsif count > 0 then
                        state <= addsub;
                    end if;
                when done =>
                    state <= state; -- do nothing
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(state) is
    begin
        case state is
            when idle =>
                -- initialize registers and other signals
                M     <= multiplicand;
                Q     <= multiplier;
                A     <= (others => '0');
                q0    <= '0';
                count <= N;
                valid <= '0';
            when addsub =>
                -- conditionally add/subtract
                if Q(1) = '0' and q0 = '1' then
                    A <= A + M;
                elsif Q(1) = '1' and q0 = '0' then
                    A <= A - M;
                end if;
            when shift =>
                -- arithmetic shift right by 1 bit
                q0 <= Q(1);
                for i in 1 to N loop
                    if i = N then
                        Q(i) <= A(1);
                    else
                        Q(i) <= Q(i + 1);
                    end if;
                end loop;
                for i in 1 to N loop
                    if i = N then
                        A(i) <= A(N);
                    else
                        A(i) <= A(i + 1);
                    end if;
                end loop;
                -- decrement counter
                count <= count - 1;
            when done =>
                -- set valid bit indicating product has been fully computed
                valid <= '1';
        end case;
    end process;
    -- product consists of the two registers A and Q as higher and lower words
    product <= (A & Q);
    -- for testing, check state transitions
    with state select
        state_out <= "00" when idle,
                     "01" when addsub,
                     "10" when shift,
                     "11" when done,
                     "XX" when others;
end booth;
```

Any other suggestions for improving bad practices are welcome.

Comment: This isn't the way. Your logic circuit can do the arithmetic step using combinatorial logic, latching that step's result into DFFs each clock. Imply that in VHDL clocked process using variables for the comb steps, assigning the step result into your signal to get the DFFs. Then it should operate in N clocks and a better solution to learn. Meanwhile (a) you must remove the gating on rising_edge(clock). You can get away with that in simulation but not in synthesized logic, causes metastability. And (b) don't load values using reset, synths to bad circuitry. It won't work, it just simulates OK.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will be updating this code with an FSM based design that addresses (a) that you have mentioned (gating on the clock edge removed). However, regarding (b) what would be the optimal way to load the operands? In my FSM the load happens in the IDLE state which is triggered with the reset signal.